# Devise a Stratagem and Swipe

Tags: feats, attack, pathfinder-2e

With [Swipe](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=142) you can attack 2 enemies, [Devise a Strategem](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=546) (DaS) lets you know the result in advance against one enemy, how do these work together?

### option 0; does not work at all

Devise a Stratagem says:

> Choose a creature you can see and roll a d20. **If you Strike the chosen creature** later this round

But with Swipe you make an untargeted Strike:

> Make a single melee Strike and **compare** the attack roll result to the ACs of up to two foes

So you can't use the DaS result for Swipe.

### option 1: you target one of them

If you roll badly for DaS targeting one of the enemies, you can still roll again, by designating the other enemy as the "primary" target.

### option 2: you can't have your cake and eat it too

If you intend to hit the target of your DaS during a Swipe, you *must* use the DaS result.

Obviously I am hoping for option 1, but is it legal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Option 2

Devise a Stratagem says:

> You assess a foe's weaknesses in combat and use them to formulate a plan of attack against your enemy. **Choose a creature** you can see and roll a d20. **If you Strike the chosen creature later this round, you must use the result of the roll you made to Devise a Stratagem for your Strike's attack roll** instead of rolling

So you must choose a specific creature, and if you later use a Stike to hit it, the strike's attack roll gets replaced.

When you Swipe, you

> Make a single melee Strike and compare the attack roll result

So it is a Strike, and it uses an attack roll, and that attack roll must be replaced.

The only thing that is not quite clear to me is if you then have to replace the roll for both creatures. I think as written you must, because Devise a Stratagem does not tell you to replace the roll for that creature, it says you replace the roll for the Strike. And there is only a single roll for the strike, which then gets compared with both creatures' ACs.